# Spring 3 catch all uncaught exceptions and rethrow

Tags: java, spring, exception

Is there a way I can create some sort of default handler for any unchecked exception that occurs, catch that and rethrow as a custom exception I created. The custom exception has a mapper that converts to a response. Im using spring 3.

Comment: It almost seems like you're asking about catching multiple exceptions... If you're asking more specifically about throwing custom exceptions, then read [this](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Java exceptions bubble up the call chain until they find a catch block that can handle them. It is better practice to catch and handle exceptions in the proper places than to override the default unchecked exception handler and let all your exceptions bubble up to it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to override the default unchecked exception handler? and why is it a bad idea?